# RxJava computation thread + Android Keystore blocking UI?

Tags: android, rx-java, android-keystore

The following minimal example, called once, blocks UI on my Motorola G6. What's wrong with it? Is the Keystore executing something on the main thread somewhere behind the scenes? (Edit: I suspect RAM issues. After changing RSA key size to 2048, it's much better, although still there is a small UI pause)

```
 Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call() throws Exception {
            KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            generator.init(256, new SecureRandom());
            Key key = generator.generateKey();

            Calendar start = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar end = Calendar.getInstance();
            end.add(Calendar.YEAR, 100);

            KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore").load(null);
            KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
            KeyPairGeneratorSpec spec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                    .setAlias("some_id")
                    .setKeySize(3072)
                    .setKeyType(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA)
                    .setStartDate(start.getTime())
                    .setEndDate(end.getTime())
                    .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                    .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN = Secured Preference Store, O = Some Name"))
                    .build();
            keyGen.initialize(spec);
            KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

            PublicKey rsaPublicKey = keyPair.getPublic();

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, rsaPublicKey);

            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, cipher);
            cipherOutputStream.write(key.getEncoded());
            cipherOutputStream.close();

            return true;
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).observeOn(Schedulers.computation()).subscribe();
```

Comment: Instead of Schedulers.computation() could u try by using  Schedulers.io()?

Comment: @arungiri_10 nope, Schedulers.io was the way I had it originally. App freezes on some few devices either way (not all devices).